# Keys and values print separate in Python but want attached to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, printing

So I would like for this code to print differently:

Python Code:

```
employees = {123: 'Bob', 124: 'Susan', 128: 'Abby', 125: 'Henry', 126: 'Edward', 127: 'James'}

for key in employees.keys():
    print("Employees Numbers: ", key)

for value in employees.values():
    print("Employee Names: ", value)
```

Prints as:

```
Employees Numbers:  123                      
Employees Numbers:  124             
Employees Numbers:  128                         
Employees Numbers:  125                
Employees Numbers:  126            
Employees Numbers:  127              
Employee Names:  Bob                
Employee Names:  Susan               
Employee Names:  Abby              
Employee Names:  Henry             
Employee Names:  Edward             
Employee Names:  James
```

Would like it to print as:

```
Employee Numbers: 123, 124, 128, 125, 126, 127                     
Employee Names: Bob, Susan, Abby, Henry, Edward
```

Comment: `print(', '.join(employees))`

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the keys like this:

```
print('Employee Numbers: {}'.format(', '.join(str(num) for num in employees.keys())))
```

Then similarly for the names:

```
print('Employee Names: {}'.format(', '.join(name for name in employees.values())))
```

Comment: for value in employees.values():
                                                  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax                                                                                                     it is pointing to the ':' at the end as to where the error is occurring

Comment: make sure you close the parentheses. this code should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the dictionary and use formatted string for for display

```
>>> employees = {123: 'Bob', 124: 'Susan', 128: 'Abby', 125: 'Henry', 126: 'Edward', 127: 'James'}
>>> print('Employee Numbers: {}'.format(', '.join(str(key) for key in employees.keys())))
Employee Numbers: 128, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127
>>> print('Employee Names: {}'.format(', '.join(value for value in employees.values())))
Employee Names: Abby, Bob, Susan, Henry, Edward, James
```

Comment: You have it very close to working... it loops thorugh 6 times each so it prints Employee Numbers: 128, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127                                                     6 times as opposed to stopping after the first time

Comment: but what you need now?

Comment: I need it to print once but with your code it prints:                                     Employee Numbers: 123, 124, 128, 125, 126, 127
Employee Numbers: 123, 124, 128, 125, 126, 127
Employee Numbers: 123, 124, 128, 125, 126, 127
Employee Numbers: 123, 124, 128, 125, 126, 127

Employee Names: Bob, Susan, Abby, Henry, Edward, James
Employee Names: Bob, Susan, Abby, Henry, Edward, James
Employee Names: Bob, Susan, Abby, Henry, Edward, James
Employee Names: Bob, Susan, Abby, Henry, Edward, James

Comment: It prints the same... I am running the data from an actual python file not the shell so could that be the problem?

Comment: So, check the actual data. if you have dictionary like your question, it will works fine

Comment: take it out of the for loop, run it exactly as he has it (or I have it in the other answer)

Answer (score 0):

First store `keys` and `values` into separate `lists` and then use `join` operator to populate them into a `string` separated by a `comma`.

For employee number, you will need to do an extra step where you convert the numbers into `strings` (since `join` operates only on `string`)

```
employees = {123: 'Bob', 124: 'Susan', 128: 'Abby', 125: 'Henry', 126: 'Edward', 127: 'James'}

numbers = list(employees.keys())
names = list(employees.values())

print("Employee Keys : ",', '.join([str(i) for i in numbers]))
print("Employee Names : ",', '.join(names))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def main():
    employees = {123: 'Bob', 124: 'Susan', 128: 'Abby', 125: 'Henry', 126: 'Edward', 127: 'James'}

    print("employees ids:", ", ".join([str(x) for x in employees]))
    print("employees names:", ", ".join([str(x) for x in employees.values()]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output:

```
employees ids: 123, 124, 128, 125, 126, 127
employees names: Bob, Susan, Abby, Henry, Edward, James
```